# How to make a timer which executes for certain amount of time

Tags: java, android, timer

I'm in the middle of a Football Match Timer project. Basically, I'm looking for an implementation of a timer which starts after pushing a `"START 1st half"` button, counts to 45 minutes, than pauses and we are able to start it again pushing `"START 2nd half"`(it would be the same button, but its text would be changed through the whole match). Then it would count from 45 minutes to 90 minutes.

I've been trying to accomplish this using `Handler()`, `Runnable()` and `onClickListener()`, but it doesn't work at all for me :( Would you give me some suggestions about how to tackle this?

```
Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {

        showTimeRemaining();
        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
    }
};
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button b = (Button) v;
            startButton(v);
            if (b.getText().equals("Mecz trwa")) {    
                timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);            
                b.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
                b.setText("Mecz trwa");
                b.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });

    public void showTimeRemaining() {
    long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
    int minutes = seconds / 60;
    seconds = seconds % 60;


    timerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
    timerTextView.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: Seems you're​ not using the button object while updating the time in the showTimeRemaining method. Also put logger or system.out.Print  statements to see whether it is getting called or not. Try this simple calc. intconds = (int) (milliseconds / 1000) % 60 ; int minutes = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60)) % 60)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some of my suggestions.

First, encapsulate your `Handler` into a class called `Timer`. This way it's easier to manipulate your timers. Here is my version:

import android.os.Handler;

```
public class Timer {
    private Handler handler;
    private boolean paused;

    private int interval;

    private Runnable task = new Runnable () {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!paused) {
                runnable.run ();
                Timer.this.handler.postDelayed (this, interval);
            }
        }
    };

    private Runnable runnable;

    public int getInterval() {
        return interval;
    }

    public void setInterval(int interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    public void startTimer () {
        paused = false;
        handler.postDelayed (task, interval);
    }

    public void stopTimer () {
        paused = true;
    }

    public Timer (Runnable runnable, int interval, boolean started) {
        handler = new Handler ();
        this.runnable = runnable;
        this.interval = interval;
        if (started)
            startTimer ();
    }
}
```

Secondly, don't use `System.currenTimeMillis`. Use something more manipulatable. Create a variable of your own that stores how many seconds are left:

```
private int secondsLeft = 60 * 45;
```

You decrement this variable every second, until it reaches zero. Then, you stop the timer, change the button's text or whatever. This logic should be put into the `Runnable` used for the handler.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try using of CountDownTimer.

Refer here for documentation and usage:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html